# replace with sed on Mac OS X Leopard doesn't do what expected

Tags: regex, macos, unix, sed

I'm trying to replace \" (backslash doouble quote) by ' (quote) using sed.

```
sed "s/\\\"/\'/g" file.txt
```

The command doesn't work as expected. It replaces all the " in the text file, not only the \".

It does the same thing as sed "s/\"/\'/g" file.txt

I'm working on Mac OS X Leopard.

Does any one have a clue?

Comment: When in doubt, add another backslash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're dealing with the infamous shell quoting problem.  Try using single quotes around the s//g instead, or add an extra escape:

```
sed "s/\\\\\"/\'/g"
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly the shell quoting problem, since the problem is in sed's interpretation of the string and not the shell's.  Sed sees s/\"/\'/g and interprets the \" the same as ".

Comment: @William - I characterize it as "shell quoting problem" because bash "swallows" one of the escapes so that sed doesn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting issues with bash are fun.

```
$ cat input
"This is an \"input file\" that has quoting issues."
$ sed -e 's/\\"/'"'"'/g' input
"This is an 'input file' that has quoting issues."
```

Note that there are three strings butted together to make the sed script:

- `s/\\"/`
- `'`
- `/g`

The first and last are quoted with single quotes, and the middle is quoted with double quotes.

Matthew's command works by joining two strings instead of three:

- `s/\\"/`
- `'/g`

where the first is single-quoted and the second double-quoted.

Comment: Nice.  You can simplify it slightly to sed -e 's/\\"/'"'/g" input

Answer (score 0):

don't have to use too many quotes. \042 octal is for `"` and \047 is octal for single quote

```
awk '{gsub("\042","\047") }{print}' file
```